# Overriding views-view-grouping.tpl.php when grouping by only one field

Tags: views, theming

I have a view being grouped by one field. I'm trying to theme the groups as a whole (wrap divs around the whole thing, essentially) and I did so by overriding `views-view-grouping.tpl.php`. However, nothing happens. Out of curiosity I added another grouping and voilá, my template override is being picked up now. Only problem is, I don't need to group by two fields, just one.

Why is it doing this? Is there a separate override for single-grouped views? What is going on and how can I get Views to pick up my override of `views-view-grouping.tpl.php` when grouping by only one field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same issue. At first I though it was connected to the current theme I was using, but after testing with a few different themes I discovered that not to be the case. I still do not understand that behavior.

As a workaround I've used views-view-unformatted--YOURVIEWMACHINENAME.tpl.php template where you can give a wrapper to a group in a single-grouped view. Here's what I had in the template:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
    <?php 
        //open group wrapper
        print '<div class="custom-class">';
    ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
    <?php
  // close group wrapper
    print '</div>'; 
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can even assign a custom class to each group by taking a certain field from $view object and transforming its value into a class name.

Of course, this method will only work for a single-grouped view. If the view will be grouped by more than one field, only the most inner group will be wrapped. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The brilliant solution by Oksana-c also works great in Drupal 8 in Twig (views-view-unformatted--my-view--my-display.html.twig):

```
{#
/**
* @file
* Theme override to display a view of unformatted rows.
*
* Available variables:
* - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
* - rows: A list of the view's row items.
*   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
*   - content: The row's content.
* - view: The view object.
* - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should 
be
*   used on rows.
*
* @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
*/
#}
<div class="grouping-row">
{% if title %}
  <div class="grouping-title">{{ title }}</div>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
     set row_classes = [
       default_row_class ? 'views-row',
     ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```